# How to pop to the previous screen with params?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm on screen A which has current state of {key:'value'} , I navigated to screen B

now I'm trying to pop from screen B to screen A again , but I don't want to lose the current state in screen A {key:'value'}

some solution is to save data in the AsynStorage , and retrive it when coming back to screen A , but that's not a good practice

.pop() do it , but what if I need to go back with additional params ?

```js
Navigation.pop(this.props.componentId, {
  passProps: {
    data: "current",
    more: "just-example",
  },
});
```

the above code, did not work

any suggestions ?

> I don't use any state management tool like Redux/Mobx ..

Comment: `the above code , did not work` what do you mean? Did it got an error?

Comment: @Vencovsky , no it popped up to the previous screen but without the any passed params

Comment: I use `react-navigation` over `react-native-navigation` so I don't know if this is possible. When you navigate to the child page, you can simply parse something like: `navigate('somePage',  { parent: this } )` in which case you can then access the parent from the child by calling `this.props.blah.blah.parent` this may be a work around for you.

Comment: @swonder it's not possible here

Answer (score 7):

I found a good solution is to send a callback function with the params

in screen A

```
  getback(success)
  {
      alert(success);
  }

  Navigation.push(this.props.componentId , { component : {
         name : "Payment",
         passProps: {
         subscription : current,
         getback: this.getback
       },
   }});
```

then in screen B , when you pop to screen A fire the getback function

```
Navigation.pop(this.props.componentId);
this.props.getback(true);
```

this worked well with me

Comment: does getback method need wrapped by useCallback?

Answer (score 2):

If the reason why you wanted `navigation.pop` is the animation, I have news for you: just use `navigation.navigate`!

When using the card presentation (for example), doing, from screen B, `navigation.navigate(screenA_Id, options)`, works like `navigation.pop`

Comment: It is a navigation stack, so the screen will be added on top of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this and I achieved with [`react-navigation`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation).

Basically, your component A will send to component B the navigation state of component A. So, For B point of view it will be the prevState before stacking B component.

So when component B navigates "back" to component A using the previous navigation state it was like your navigation state never changed and now you could use the second parameter of `navigate` to send params back to component A.

This simple example illustrate this practice and I think it is totally valid and no `AsyncStorage` usage.

```js
// In Component A use a custom prevState when goes to Component B
const { navigation } = this.props;

navigation.navigate('ComponentB', { prevState: navigation.state });
```

```js
// In Component B use this custom goBack to "pop" to last screen
function goBack(data) {
  const { navigation } = this.props;

  const { routeName, key } = navigation.getParam('prevState');

  navigation.navigate({ routeName, key, params: data });
}
```

```js
// And finally in Component A again you could get data like this
function getDataFromComponentB() {
  const { navigation } = this.props;

  // It is null if no parameters are specified!
  return navigation.state.params;
}
```

Comment: I never worked with `react-native-navigation` and I am sorry to not provide a specific answer with this lib. Maybe my answer could inspire you to do the same as I do.

Answer (score 0):

As Terrance suggested. you can use a callback in the props and fire it before pop back to the previous page

answer source: [React Native Pass properties on navigator pop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29463738/6832075)

Answer (score 0):

I was working on similar thing which I wan't to popToTop and pass some params when I came back to top of the stack.

here how I did it in react navigation 5 :-

```
props.navigation.reset({ // I did reset my stack using navigation.reset() instead of using popToTop
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        {
          name: "Home", //name of screen which you wan't to come back to it
          params: { isDialogOpen: true }, // params you wanna pass to the screen
        },
      ],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain in deep
Your stack now is [A, B, C] (current in C)

```js
// make another A
navigation.push("A") // => [A,B,C,A]
// back to A with params
navigation.navigate(A, params) // => [A]
// just back
navigation.back() // => [A,B]
```